# Automatically download android TTS engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have developed an app based on TTS for Android 2.3. 
I am noticing that in recent version of Android (4.2.2) for example, no default TTS language where installed by default, you have to manually download them by going into:
Settings --> Language and input --> Text to speech output --> Google Text-To-speech --> Install voice data

Is there a way to install a language automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to install a language automatically?

Yes, but that will not happen automatically (without user consent) as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA):

> *Since the installation of the data can be interrupted or **declined by the user**, the application shouldn't expect successful installation upon return from that intent...*

Anyhow, you can trigger the installation with something like [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/tts/TtsEngineSettingsFragment.java):

```
/**
 * Ask the current default engine to launch the matching INSTALL_TTS_DATA activity
 * so the required TTS files are properly installed.
 */
private void installVoiceData() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.tts"/*replace with the package name of the target TTS engine*/);
    try {
        Log.v(TAG, "Installing voice data: " + intent.toUri(0));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to install TTS data, no acitivty found for " + intent + ")");
    }
}
```