# Text To Speech is not working in Ginger Bread - Android 2.3

Tags: android

I am developing a text to speech application.
All code is working fine in Android 4.0 Ice cream sandwich and above.
But in Android 2.3 ginger bread no voice is coming without any error.
Voice coming in emulator but not in phone.
I have checked my app on two handsets:

1. Xperia x10 and
2. Galaxy pop mini having ginger bread.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TTS extends Activity implements OnInitListener{

    Context context;
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private ImageButton playTTS,stopTTS,clearTTS;
    private EditText textTTS;
    private Spinner selectVoices;
    public static int spinnerPos;
    private String spinnerList[] = {"...Select Voices..."," Voice 1"," Voice 2"," Voice 3"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tts);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        selectVoices = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        playTTS = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b_playTTS);
        stopTTS = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b_stopTTS);
        clearTTS = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b_clearTTS);

        textTTS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_entertext);

        Typeface  mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"mvboli.ttf");
        textTTS.setTypeface(mFace);

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TTS.this, R.layout.spinnerlayout, spinnerList){

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mvboli.ttf");
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

                    return v;
            }


            public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
                     View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

                    Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mvboli.ttf");
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

                    return v;
            }
    };
        selectVoices.setAdapter(aa);

        // spinner on item click event
        selectVoices.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinnerPos = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        // button on click event
        playTTS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (spinnerPos) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please choose a voice type !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    tts.setPitch(1.0f);
                    speakOut();
                    Log.d("TextToSpeech","in the onclick1");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    tts.setPitch(0.2f);
                    speakOut();
                    Log.d("TextToSpeech","in the onclick2");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    //pitch = 0.2f;
                    tts.setPitch(2.0f);
                    speakOut();
                    Log.d("TextToSpeech","in the onclick3");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

        });

        // clear button click event
        stopTTS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tts.stop();

            }
        });

        // back button click event
        clearTTS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textTTS.setText("");            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private void speakOut() {

        String text = textTTS.getText().toString();
        Log.d("TextToSpeech","in the spkout");

        tts.speak(text,tts.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } 
            else{
                if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.getDefault()) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE || tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.getDefault()) == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE)
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }



}
```

Please help.

Comment: You might not have a default speech engine installed. Check text to speech settings and say install voice data.

Comment: thanx ashwin...but is there any way that when anyone install my app then  the default engine installs automatically OR how can i give my speech engine to my app...???

Comment: Yes there is a way. Check answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way but not without user consent.

```
private void installVoiceData() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.tts"/*replace with the package name of the target TTS engine*/);
    try {
        Log.v(TAG, "Installing voice data: " + intent.toUri(0));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to install TTS data, no acitivty found for " + intent + ")");
    }
}
```

Originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16836553/1443981)